# Run 2 applications on same port and same ip adress with iis

Tags: iis

I'm trying (as the title explains) to run two applications both on the same port and same ip adress as i have one server with only one ip adress and one hostname.
And for security reasons i only have one open port.
So i'm using iis and i want to know what's the best way to do so.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use different host names. Or different paths, if your applications support that.

Comment: There must be *some* way to distinguish between the application, for example by an URL path prefix. Use this prefix to configure IIS to choose the proper application.

Comment: Using host names (host headers) will only be usefull in the local network not for external access.
How do I know if my application support different paths ?

Comment: “Using host names (host headers) will only be usefull in the local network not for external access.” – No? It’s how most Internet hosting works.

Comment: Is there a full guide on how to use them on my server (dns server in iis) ?